# Parse Apple Plist files in android

Tags: android

I have onle application in which i have to parse plist files. I dont found any usefull link for that I have following plist file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com        
 /DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">

<plist version="1.0">

<dict>
<key>About The Firm</key>
<array>
    <string>Firm Details</string>
    <string>Verdicts</string>
    <string>Read Our Disclaimer</string>
</array>
<key>Attorneys</key>
<array>
    <string>Jerrold S. Parker</string>
    <string>Herbert L. Waichman</string>
    <string>Andres F. Alonso</string>
    <string>Jordan L. Chaikin</string>
    <string>Raymond C. Silverman</string>
    <string>Brett A. Zekowski</string>
    <string>Fred R. Rosenthal</string>
    <string>David B. Krangle</string>
    <string>Douglas A. Kugal</string>
    <string>Melanie H. Muhlstock</string>
    <string>Herman Badillo</string>
    <string>Jay L. T. Breakstone</string>
    <string>Michael R. Bluman</string>
    <string>Daniel C. Burke</string>
    <string>Peter J. Cambs</string>
    <string>Gary P. Falkowitz</string>
    <string>April S. Goodwin</string>
    <string>Michael Hugo</string>
    <string>James G. Kapralos</string>
    <string>Christina J. Kazepis</string>
    <string>Brett R. Leitner</string>
    <string>Matthew J. McCauley</string>
    <string>Allan M. Silverstein</string>
    <string>Lauren B. Sutton</string>
    <string>Justin Varughese</string>
</array>
<key>Disclaimer</key>
<array>
    <string>Read Our Disclaimer</string>
</array>
<key>Practice Areas</key>
<array>
    <string>Auto Accidents</string>
    <string>Defective Drugs</string>
    <string>Defective Medical Device</string>
    <string>Nursing Home Abuse</string>
</array>
```

Please give me some solution for that

Answer (score 2):

Use [SAXParser](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/xml/parsers/SAXParser.html) to parse it as xml. You should be able to find good tutorials for that.

Answer (score 1):

If you still need it.
Maybe you can use [Android PList Parser](https://github.com/tenaciousRas/android-plist-parser), is Sax-Based.